# Mixed mode solution copying output of one project to global output

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-c++, mixed-mode

I have a project with a VC++ shim interfacing a C++ API (OpenCV, headers plus lib files), for use with a .net application. The mixed mode is confusing. I'd like the shim to be a prerequisite for the application build and the output dll to be copied to the debug/release output.

How with Visual Studio's macros is it possible to access another project's paths to access the build output, or make the shim a dependency from the perspective of the build sequence?